# Как из программы на c++ запустить nodejs в silent режиме

Tags: c++, windows, node.js

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    char fname[] = "D:/node.exe run";
    char cfname[] = "D:/node";

    STARTUPINFO cif;
    ZeroMemory(&cif, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    CreateProcessA(NULL, fname, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
        CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, NULL,
        cfname, &cif, &pi);
}
```

При запуске таким способом вылазит стандартное окно ноды, что крайне не желательно...

Comment: Попробуйте так: CreateProcessA(NULL, fname, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP **| CREATE_NO_WINDOW**, NULL, cfname, &cif, &pi);

Comment: @Embedder, спасибо, это сработало

Comment: Оформьте и отметьте как ответ пожалуйста, чтобы можно было найти в поиске.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для запуска дочернего **консольного** процесса без создания дополнительного окна можно использовать функцию `CreateProcessA`/`CreateProcessW`, в которой задать параметр `dwCreationFlags` равным `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` (или его комбинация с другими необходимыми флагами). Например так (код из вопроса):

```
CreateProcessA(NULL, fname, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
    NULL, cfname, &cif, &pi);
```

Полное описание функции и примеры её использования можно найти в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).